# How i can index Neo4j nodes?

Tags: graph, indexing, neo4j, nodes, cypher

i am using auto_inedx for some attributes and it works good
for example :

```
Start myNode=node:node_auto_index( name = "Masoud" )
```

but when i have 2 groups , for example Users and Employees and its possible that a user and a employee have same name ,
i search for answer and find this :

```
START movie=node:movies("title:M*") 
MATCH movie<-[:ACTS_IN]-actor
WHERE actor.name = "Kevin Bacon"
RETURN movie.title
```

what is movies() ???
is that a group of nodes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

movies is name of the index. In case of automatic index, we can use node_auto_index. there is an option to manually create an index. In this particular example, movies is an index name for the property title.

When you have two different nodes, users and employees, you can create two different indices
1. one for 'name' property in users node
2. other for 'name' property in employee node.

Example:
If you are using Spring Data Neo4j, you can achieve the indexing using annotation,

```
@Indexed(indexName = "email", indexType = IndexType.FULLTEXT) 
String email .
```

If you are using Java client, you can find example in the following neo4j tutorial, docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/indexing-create.html

Hope that helps

Comment: can you write an example for me ?

Comment: Adding index through cypher query is not available right now, as per the discussion in group, that support would be included from 1.10. If you are using Spring Data Neo4j, you can achieve the indexing using annotation, @Indexed(indexName = "email", indexType = IndexType.FULLTEXT) String email . If you are using Java client, you can find example in the following neo4j tutorial, http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/indexing-create.html

Comment: i want to use a unique database for neo4jServer and embeded java code . but i can't ... i use same data folder for neo4j.bat and embedded java database , but results is diffrent

Comment: its ambiguous can you elaborate more?